# Graceful upgrading of an anchor element

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to add a JavaScript functionality to an array of thumbnails such that the image would expand upon clicking instead of opening in the current window. I am thinking of having a function within the `onclick` attribute, but I don't think this work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 function expand(){
  this.height = 200;
  this.width = 200;
 }
</script>

<a href='/image_1.jpg' onclick='expand()'>
 <img src='/image_1.jpg'>
</a>
```

If JavaScript is not enabled, I would like the link to work. Any idea how to go about doing this? Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give `this` as a variable in the function for example `ths`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 function expand(ths){
    $(ths).find('img').height('200');
    $(ths).find('img').width('200');
  return false;
 }
</script>

<a href='/image_1.jpg' onclick='expand(this)'>
 <img src='/image_1.jpg'>
</a>
```

And `return false` says Prusse.

** UPDATED **
If you want to resize image, you must call the image and no link.

Comment: Still no response. Could it be because this is referring to the link and not the image?

Comment: Yes, have you considered using jQuery? Would make this a lot easier?

Comment: @SamGiles, I try to avoid it if it can be done with Javascript easily, not sure about this case though.

Comment: @M1K1O, any way to reference the <img> tag with Javascript?

Comment: I do not know. I think, jQuery is better. Just add  `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` to header.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `onclick` handler:

Instead:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("the-id-of-a");
elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) { /* handle event */ e.preventDefault(); return false; });
```

See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `onclick` handler return `false`. Using inline handlers like in your example:

```
<a href='/image_1.jpg' onclick='expand(); return false;'>
```